# Sharepoint List Filter option is loading slow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

My list has **5129 items** but I have increased threshold limit up to 5 lac in SharePoint on-prem environment. When a normal user tries to apply a filter to the list the loads very slow. **But it not happening using system account. It option loads fast using system account. Also, there are only 10 options in the filter**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you using item level permissions on the list?

A System account will bypass permission checks on a list and that could explain the performance gain. Otherwise, get a fiddler trace and check where the time is wasted...

Also you could consider indexing the field in question for a better performance... The filter has no clue that there are only 10 items available.

Comment: It was working fine before 5000 items I guess. Also, Indexing is done already. I don't know how to use fiddler and trace.

Comment: Dont mess with the list view limits. They can cause SQL lock escalations. And are you using item level permissions?

Comment: Yes, Item level permissions are there. Also, my data is 5137 also it is increasing day by day. Please Help

Comment: Have you tried indexing the field? What field type is it? Maybe move it to a MMS field and use that as an external filter?

Comment: My first solution was indexing also Those columns are of choice field. I am new in SharePoint, Don't know much about MMS field and external filter?

Comment: MMS fields allow you to have a filter in the menu without the need to query all items. Or build a tiny list to send a filter to the listview Webpart itself - default UI sucks for it but its an option.

Comment: Where are "item level permissions" defined?

Answer (score 0):

You can narrow down this issue as the following:

1. clear the browser cache.
2. Clear SharePoint Configuration cache.
3. Run->IISRest.